# Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: histogram, numeric

I want to make multiple histogram for my data but it always throws an error.

> Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric

my data structure:

[image]

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra96w.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.